# why location.href does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery 
Why location.href does not work 
This is my code

```
function RemoveProduct(Seolink) {
        $('#p' + Seolink).remove();
        var LinkToGo = 'localhost:5000/Home/Compare?';
        for (var i = 0; i < $('#CompareSection .hoverable.grey.lighten-2').length; i++) {
            LinkToGo += 'Product=DKP' + $('#CompareSection .hoverable.grey.lighten-2:eq(' + i + ')').attr('id')
                        .substring(1, $('#CompareSection .hoverable.grey.lighten-2:eq(' + i + ')').attr('id').length) + '&';
        }
        LinkToGo = LinkToGo.substring(0, LinkToGo.length - 1);
        location.href = LinkToGo;
        //window.location.href = LinkToGo;
        //document.location.href = LinkToGo;
    }
```

Comment: We can't possibly know with you either providing a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or at the very least telling us what your `LinkToGo` currently resolves to, whether jQuery is definitely defined and what your `SeoLink` variable is.

Comment: Before location.reload i put a alert "alert(LinkToGo)" and the result is "localhost:5000/Home/Compare?Product=DKP10000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing protocol or at least leading `//` so browser will assume that as a relative url and append that value to whatever current url is

Try changing to

```
var LinkToGo = '//localhost:5000/Home/Compare?';
//OR
var LinkToGo = 'http://localhost:5000/Home/Compare?';
```